# BIRT report viewer page > printer icon

Tags: printing, birt, maximo

We have receved a request to hide the printer icon on the BIRT Report Viewer page.   The reason for the request is that we are running reports from Maximo 7.5 (Select Action > Run Reports) and when the BIRT Report Viewer page is displayed, users click the Printer icon instead of Export Report icon.

I've search for a solution and read several comments on BIRT Report Viewer in IE versus other Web browsers and how to make adjustments in IE tools.  We are using IE 9 by the way.   I've also found solutions that suggest to modify Adobe settings but nothing specifically about the printer icon.

I simply want to hide the printer icon in the BIRT REport Viewer page.  How do I do this?

Comment: What type of viewer do you use? What is printer icon?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it's not all that easy. The best way I can think of is either deleting the printer icon or hiding it from view. Either way you must find the BIRT installation folder for the application.

To hide the printer icon from view (this is what I recommend), search for the style.css file. For me it's located here:
        `<birt_371(installation)>\plugins\org.eclipse.birt.report.viewer_3.7.1.v20110905\birt\webcontent\birt\styles`

When you find it, open it for editing (notepad++ is a great tool, but you can use plain notepad too).

Add the bottom of the file, hit enter for a new line and put the following:

```
/*Hide Printer Icon*/
input[name=print] 
{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

That should solve your problem.